How to set application name in PySide6
I wanted to change the name of my application using setApplicationName() but when the program starts, the application is displayed as "Python" on my desktop.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from projects_window import ProjectsWindow
from edit_window import EditWindow



app = QApplication.instance() or QApplication([])
app.setApplicationName("Reportator") 
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))  # Укажите путь к вашей иконке


def run_projects_window():
    """Функция для отображения окна выбора проекта"""
    window = ProjectsWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

    # Возвращаем решение пользователя: новый проект или открыть проект
    return window.get_project_decision()


def run_edit_window():
    """Функция для отображения окна редактирования"""
    edit_window = EditWindow()
    edit_window.show()
    app.exec()


def main():
    # Сначала вызываем окно выбора проекта
    project_decision = run_projects_window()

    # Выводим результат в терминал
    if project_decision:
        print("Создать новый проект")
    else:
        print("Открыть существующий проект")

    # Затем запускаем окно редактирования
    run_edit_window()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tried to use app.setApplicationName("Reportator") to change the name of the app, but it didn't help. The application is always displayed as "Python".

I think the function you're looking for is QGuiApplication::setApplicationDisplayName.

Set window tittle?

What is "my desktop"? What OS? If on Linux, what distro/wm/dm, and with X or Wayland? Did you use setWindowTitle()? Please provide a proper [mre], and add further environment details.

Also, please either remove or translate comments in the code, this is an English language website, code comments in other languages are just distracting and annoying.
